# Shared module variable doesn't update?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I'm trying to share (set/get) a variable between packages and modules, but the value isn't changing.

What am I doing wrong?

**shared.py**

```
my_shared_value = 'init'
```

**mod_write.py**

```
import mylib.shared
mylib.shared.my_shared_value = 'changed'
```

**mod_read.py**

```
import mylib.shared

while True:
    # outputs always 'init' but should output 'changed' 
    # after mod_set.py was executed.
    print(mylib.shared.my_shared_value)
```

**Execution** (same virtual environment)

```
# Terminal 1
python ./mod_read.py # outputs 'init', runs forever

# Terminal 2
python ./mod_write.py # doesn't affect the output of Terminal 1
```

Comment: [mcve], please. Show us how you import and execute all of this code. Because there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks, I'll add more information.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I updated my answer. Does it help?

Comment: It does, yes. Thanks.

Comment: Dupe: [How to share variables across scripts in python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1829116)

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks again. If you post the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the result of the mod_write.py file you need to import that file as well(but after your first import).

In your case, you execute files separately, so you don't see the expected result.

Try this way:

```
import mylib.shared
import mylib.mod_write

while True:
    # outputs always 'init' but should output 'changed' 
    # after mod_set.py was executed.
    print(mylib.shared.my_shared_value)
```